# Where's my python2 interpreter?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

Since installing Anaconda on my mac, both the term 'python' and 'python3' launch the python 3.5.1 Anaconda interpreter, despite me also having 2.6 and 2.7 installed (well, they came preinstalled on the mac). 
So far I've been learning odd bits here and there in python 3 but I've started a course which requires 2.7 so I need to know how to use it.

Proper noob question I know, but I am a noob...

Comment: try enter 'python2.7' on your terminal and hit 'Enter', it should launch python2.7

Comment: Damn it! I was typing python27! Easiest question ever, eh? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typing in `python2.7` and hit `Enter`

If you want to know the path

try `which python2.7`, for example:

```
$which python2.7                                                                                                                                                                       
/Users/haifzhan/.virtualenvs/env-2.7/bin/python2.7
```